# Working out starting time when user has chosen the gmt time

Tags: php, time, gmt

I have a loop that checks to see if a user's daily game has started based on time().  The event starting time is based on the GMT time that the user has chosen.

My problem is that I can't seem to work out how to get the starting time - once a day I loop through the database and create all the games for the day; if a user chooses the GMT time of 20 (for example) how do I work out the time() for the next time GMT20 occurs.

EDIT:
I think the assumption here is that the daily loop is made at GMT +0, it's not.  The daily loop can be anytime during the day, it happens after a certain event happens.
So I need the NEXT unix timestamp where GMT +20 (for example) happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your date stored? As a unix time stamp?  Just add 24 hours to it (in seconds).

```
<?
$time=$time+(24*60*60);
```

Comment: There are 1) `+=` operator or 2) `strtotime` function. Either can help to make your code better

Comment: @zerkms I don't see how strtotime is going to help, and I did it 'long' hand as I didn't want to confuse the guy with an operator he might not be familiar with

Comment: `$time = strotimte('+1 day', $time);`. Come on, `+=` **is not** a rocket science. It is language basics.

Comment: @zerkms to a guy that doesn't know how to add 24 hours to a time, it might be rocket science.  I'll give you the strtotime thing, but that isn't going to help the guy understand what is going on.

Comment: if he doesn't understand how to add 86400 seconds to current time - nothing will help him until he get how to program.

Comment: I think the assumption here is that the daily loop is made at GMT +0, it's not.  The daily loop can be anytime during the day, it happens after a certain event happens.

Comment: @james clifton Perhaps you should try and reword your question, it doesn't make a ton of sense.